# SQL excluding current row in average calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `car` with fields `model`, `engine`, `sales`, `type`, where type can only be one of 4: sedan,coupe,sports,hatchback.

I need to find which car models have sold over double the average of all the other cars of this type. I know how to find an average for all cars of each type, but I cannot work out how to find the average for each type excluding the current row.

My idea was something like:
`select model, sales from car group by type having sales > 2*avg(average sales for this type not including the sales of one car)`

I have also tried to add `case when` into the average calculation but I could not manage to make it work.

Comment: `avg(...) filter (where ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function with a [framing clause and a frame exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html).  You need two levels of query, as windows functions cannot be in WHERE or HAVING of their same level:

```
select * from (
    select 
       *,
       avg(sales) over (partition by type rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following exclude current row) as avg_other from car
) as foo
where sales>2*avg_other
```